# identity_insert error where I haven't set my identity field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, table-per-type

I just resolved a problem described here:
[Need help migrating existing model to include table per type inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994729/need-help-migrating-existing-model-to-include-table-per-type-inheritance)

However, now my inserts are giving this error

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Client' when
IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF
```

However, I do not set the clientID anywhere in my create method. From the output console I can see that it is trying to insert a value into clientID

```
Error executing command: INSERT [dbo].[Client]([ClientID], ...(other column names)
VALUES (@0, ...(other values)
```

I know the clientID field needs to be the same for both tables. So I think it might be inserting into the person table and grabbing the generated value and trying to insert that into the client table directly. But that's just a hunch.

Any ideas?

Code for create:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "firstName,lastName, ...(other client fields)")] 
                                            Client client, string[] selectedPrograms, 
                                                           string[] selectedIncomeSources, string [] incomeAmounts, 
                                                           string [] selectedNonCashBenefitSources, string [] nonCashBenefitAmounts,
                                                           string [] selectedDisabilities, string [] markedDisabilities)
    {
        client.Programs = new List<Program>();
        client.clientIncomeSources = new List<SourceOfIncomeAmounts>();
        client.clientNonCashBenefitIncomeSources = new List<SourceOfNonCashBenefitAmounts>();
        client.clientDisabilities = new List<MarkedDisability>();
        if (selectedPrograms != null)
        {
            //initialize the Programs navigation property as an empty collection
            foreach (var program in selectedPrograms)
            {
                var programToAdd = db.Programs.Find(int.Parse(program));
                client.Programs.Add(programToAdd);
            }
        }

        if (selectedIncomeSources != null)
        {
            //initialize the Income Sources navigation property as an empty collection
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var incomeSource in selectedIncomeSources)
            {
                var incomeSourceToAdd = db.IncomeSources.Find(int.Parse(incomeSource));
                var incomeSourceAmountToAdd = new SourceOfIncomeAmounts();
                incomeSourceAmountToAdd.ClientID = client.ClientID;
                incomeSourceAmountToAdd.sourceOfIncomeID = incomeSourceToAdd.sourceOfIncomeID;
                incomeSourceAmountToAdd.sourceOfIncomeName = incomeSourceToAdd.sourceOfIncomeName;
                incomeSourceAmountToAdd.Amount = Convert.ToInt32(incomeAmounts[i]);
                client.clientIncomeSources.Add(incomeSourceAmountToAdd);
                i++;
            }
        }

        if (selectedNonCashBenefitSources != null)
        {
            //initialize the Non-Cash Benefit Sources navigation property as an empty collection                
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var nonCashIncomeSource in selectedNonCashBenefitSources)
            {
                var nonCashBenefitSourceToAdd = db.NonCashBenefitSources.Find(int.Parse(nonCashIncomeSource));
                var nonCashBenefitAmountToAdd = new SourceOfNonCashBenefitAmounts();
                nonCashBenefitAmountToAdd.ClientID = client.ClientID;
                nonCashBenefitAmountToAdd.sourceOfNonCashBenefitID = nonCashBenefitSourceToAdd.sourceOfNonCashBenefitID;
                nonCashBenefitAmountToAdd.sourceOfNonCashBenefitName = nonCashBenefitSourceToAdd.sourceOfNonCashBenefitName;
                nonCashBenefitAmountToAdd.Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(nonCashBenefitAmounts[i]);
                client.clientNonCashBenefitIncomeSources.Add(nonCashBenefitAmountToAdd);
                i++;
            }
        }

        if (selectedDisabilities != null)
        {
            //initialize the Disabilities navigation property as an empty collection
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var disability in selectedDisabilities)
            {
                var disabilityToAdd = db.Disabilities.Find(int.Parse(disability));
                var markedDisabilityToAdd = new MarkedDisability();
                markedDisabilityToAdd.ClientID = client.ClientID;
                markedDisabilityToAdd.DisabilityID = disabilityToAdd.DisabilityID;
                markedDisabilityToAdd.disabilityName = disabilityToAdd.disabilityName;
                markedDisabilityToAdd.isMarked = markedDisabilities[i];
                client.clientDisabilities.Add(markedDisabilityToAdd);
                i++;
            }
        }

        //used for checking errors in the ModelState
//        var errors = ModelState
//.Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
//.Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors })
//.ToArray();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Clients.Add(client);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        PopulateAllCheckBoxLists(client);
        return PartialView("_Create", client);
```

Comment: Can you post your code? If your Client Id field is not explicitly set, then you might be trying to insert a value of 0 into the table.

Comment: Also, what is the definition of the model - specifically the key field.

Comment: I added the code for the create. The error occurs at saveChanges. After stepping through the debugger, it looks like the ID it has is 0. Is there a way to make sure the database is generating the ID?